# Center background for inline block

Tags: css

Given HTML:

```
<div id="title">Text</div>
<div class="circlecontainer">
    <div class="circle">Hello</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.circlecontainer {
    background: #E0E;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.circle {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#000
}
.circle:hover {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S329D/4/

I would like the black circle to be vertically centered when not hovered over.

But when I set `vertical-align:middle`, the text looks screwed up:

http://jsfiddle.net/S329D/5/

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the line-height is still 200px. Try this:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.circlecontainer {
    background: #E0E;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.circle {
    line-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#000
}
.circle:hover {
    width:200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S329D/7/

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the border-radius the box is not centered, so the circle is not centered too

You need to work with the `margin-top`. I've edited [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/S329D/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a span tag inside the circle div element with style "vertical-align: middle;" and remove the "vertical-align: middle;" of the circle class.

```
<div class="circle">
    <span style=" vertical-align: middle;">Hello</span>
</div>
```

The problem is because of the height of the circle class change also affect the text element. With the span, it does not.